# Groovy ConfigSlurper: how to modify a closure in a config?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to modify a grails BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.50"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    }
}
```

Especially I want to add a plugin and modify another one.

I tried it with `ConfigSlurper`:

```
def conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(buildConfig).toURL())
def plugins = conf.grails.project.dependency.resolution 
println "found plugins: $plugins"
plugins.each {
    println it
}
```

The access to `conf.grails.project.dependency` works fine but `conf.grails.project.dependency.resolution` is a closure and I don't know how to access or even modify this section.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know grails enough to make some opinionated guess, but it seems to me this config file doesn't conform to [`ConfigSlurper` expected syntax](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper). If what you want to parse isn't very long, you can try intercepting it yourself:

```
class PluginConfig {
  def compileLibs = []
  def runtimeLibs = []
  def version

  def build(version) { this.version = version } 
  def compile(lib) { compileLibs << lib }
  def runtime(lib) { runtimeLibs << lib }
}


def conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("BuildConfig.groovy").toURL())
def plugins = conf.grails.project.dependency.resolution

def lib = new PluginConfig()

plugins.delegate = lib // magick!!
plugins()

assert lib.compileLibs == [":scaffolding:2.0.1", ':cache:1.1.1']
assert lib.runtimeLibs == [
    ":hibernate:3.6.10.7", 
    ":database-migration:1.3.8", 
    ":jquery:1.10.2.2", 
    ":resources:1.2.1"
]
assert lib.version == ":tomcat:7.0.50"
```

No idea how to rewrite this to a file (easily) after the change, though. Maybe using Grails own config parser might be a better idea; it must have a representation of the config when it parses the file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no perfect way for doing this: all available parsers/slurpers drop the comments of your configuration. So even if you would modify the result from the config slurper and write it back, it wouldn't be what you are looking for.

You also have t consider that people might use variables for version numbers and other unexpected stuff.

So I guess the best way to modify the config is to use some regular expressions and hope that you users have a standard configuration...